# Comparing histograms with chi-squared distance

Tags: opencv, statistics

Different papers/libraries seem to have a different way of computing the chi squared distance, for instance in [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html) it's expressed in one way while in this [paper](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~ofirpele/publications/ECCV2010.pdf) it's expressed in a different manner.

My first question is, what's the difference between the two formulas, i.e. why in one formula we divide by the value of one bin while in the other we divide by the sum of the two bins?

Secondly, should the histograms be normalized, if so why? The chi-squared **statistic** doesn't require that but the general consensus is to normalize the histogram before using a chi-squared **distance**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is wrong. The implementation is correct inside OpenCV. Take a look at this [bug post.](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2199)

Also, normalising a histogram does not really change its pattern or "shape". Only the scale is brought down. So as long as you're working independent of scale, which you probably are if you're looking at how much one histogram "resembles" another, normalising should only make calculations faster (hopefully).